# How can I create space between my inline-block checkboxes in CSS

Tags: html, css, checkbox

I have created list of `checkboxes` and used `border-radius` on the label, now border of each checkbox touches each other or goes through each other's border.
[image]

CSS

```
.interest {
    display:inline-block !important;
}

.bubble {
    position: absolute;
    left: -9999px;
    top: 0;
}

.circle {
    border: 1px solid #000;
    padding: 15px;
    border-radius: 50%;
}
```

[fiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/phutis/8t2j01j0/)

Comment: Try `display:block;` instead maybe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would simply encourage you to add `margin` to your label.

```
label {
    margin: 30px 2px;
    float: left;
}
```

Check this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jxjzgn3x/):

Answer (score 1):

Simply add `display: inline-block;`to the .circle class and it will be perfect.

http://codepen.io/diego-fortes/pen/bBpRbx

Answer (score -3):

First you didn't add the html so I don't know which html tags are you attributing those values to. Second, I think you can set some margins on the bubbles, if those are the bubbles in your views:

```
 .interest {
    display:inline-block !important;
}

.bubble {
    margin: 5px;
    position: absolute;
    left: -9999px;
    top: 0;
}

.circle {
    border: 1px solid #000;
    padding: 15px;
    border-radius: 50%;
}
```

Comment: Check the fiddle!